# Use layout for mail template in Phalcon\Mailer

Tags: phalcon

I use Phalcon\Mailer for sending mails.

Can I use the layout for the letter template?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible via [`createMessageFromView`](https://github.com/phalcon-ext/mailer/blob/5c29a53e6eda80cc2bf6db0bce8740a243fc2d2a/src/Manager.php#L112).

Example:

```
$myVariables = [];
/** @var \Phalcon\Ext\Mailer\Manager $mailer */
$mailer = $app->getDI()->get('mailer');

$message = $mailer->createMessageFromView('path/to/template', compact('myVariables'));
$message
    ->to('user@mail.com')
    ->subject('Hello World')
    ->from('me@mail.com', 'John Doe');

$message->send();
```

Comment: it is a template. But what about layout?

Comment: I'm not sure what you trying to achieve, can you update a question and provide a sample of your layout?